# How to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer

Tags: sbt, predictionio

I am using PredictionIo for machine learning. And i use a older template. When i build it, all is okay. But when i want to train with `pio train` i got this error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer
```

In order to resolve my probleme, i add the following lines in my build.sbt

```
 "org.apache.lucene" % "lucene-core" % "4.10.0" % "provided",
 "org.apache.lucene"       %  "lucene-analyzers-common" % "4.10.0" % "provided"
```

I build the template and train the engine again but i have same errors. 
Why the dependencies are not resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

You are telling sbt that your two dependencies will be provided by the application server.  Does your environment actually provide the libraries? If not, remove `% "provided"` and rebuild.